# TYPO3: Disable cache of custom DataProcessor output

Tags: typo3

I have an own DataProcessor, fetching and returing a random record.
This works as long as cache is disabled. How can I disable caching of this specific dataprocessor to display another result on every page load?
Like COA_INT would do?

My DataProcessor:

```
public function process(
    ContentObjectRenderer $cObj, 
    array $contentObjectConfiguration, 
    array $processorConfiguration, 
    array $processedData): array 
    {
        $heroResult = $this->heroQueryBuilder->fetchRandom($cObj->data['uid']);
        $heros = $this->dataMapper->map(Hero::class, $heroResult);
        if (count($heros)) {
            $hero = $heros[0];
            if ($hero instanceof Hero) {
                $targetVariableName = $cObj->stdWrapValue('as', $processorConfiguration, 'hero');
                $processedData[$targetVariableName] = $hero;
            }
        }
        return $processedData;
    }
```

My query builder statement, returning one result sorted random:

```
public function fetchRandom(int $pageUid, int $limit = 1): array
    {
        return $this->queryBuilder
            ->select('*')
            ->where(
                $this->queryBuilder->expr()->eq('pid', $this->queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($pageUid, \PDO::PARAM_INT))
            )
            ->addSelectLiteral('rand() AS random_sort')
            ->orderBy('random_sort')
            ->from(self::TABLE_NAME)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAll();
    }
```

Calling the dataProcessor in my page object:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        dataProcessing {
            20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
            20 {
                special = list
                special.value = 1
                as = rootpage
                dataProcessing {
                    10 = Vendor\Extension\DataProcessing\HeroProcessor
                    10 {
                        as = hero
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Rendering the result in my page layout

```
    <f:if condition="{rootpage.0.hero}">
        <div class="c-page__hero">
            <f:render partial="Page/Hero/Hero" arguments="{hero:rootpage.0.hero}" />
        </div>
    </f:if>
```

How can I disable caching just for this specific DataProcessor? Do I have to convert the cObj e.g. by calling $cObj->convertToUserIntObject()? Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think the DataProcessor result is cached but your TypoScript object is. You can wrap your FLUIDTEMPLATE (I suppose that is where your DataProcesor is attached) in a COA_INT for example.

Comment: @JonasEberle Thanks for your hint. I updated my thread to show, how I implement that. As there is no specific fluid template, I guess "dataProcessing" does not have an own content element renderer?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a COA_INT object. Thought, there might be a better way without having to use f:cObject viewhelper.

```
lib.hero = COA_INT
lib.hero {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = {$pmWebsite.view.partialRootPath}/Page/Hero/Hero.html
        dataProcessing {
            10 = Vendor\Extension\DataProcessing\HeroProcessor
            10 {
                pid = 1
                as = hero
            }
        }
    }
}
```